# Android Instant App

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I got this error in "Declare Website Association" of "App link Assistant". Does anyone know how to solve that problem. I am very new to Android Instant App.[image]

Comment: Did you upload assetlinks.json file at https://myinstnatapp.droppages.com/.well-known/

Comment: Do u hav an example to upload assetlinks.json to the website.

Comment: That depends on how your site is hosted. In your case, it looks like you'll need to create a folder called ".well-known" inside the dropbox folder that corresponds to your site, then save the assetlinks.json file in that folder. Note that it will probably show as a hidden folder so it may be hard to find once you've created it.

Answer (score 1):

1) Click on save file.

2) Create .well-known folder and save it there

3) Now upload your .well-known folder to your website. Done.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on Instant App recently.I see your mistake. Maybe the following problem happened:

1) Add it to the strings.xml file, like this following:

```
<string name="asset_statements" translatable="false">[{\n  \"relation\": [\"delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls\"],\n  \"target\": {\n    \"namespace\": \"web\",\n    \"site\": \"myinstnatapp.droppages.com\",\n  }\n}]</string>
```

and add the following to AndroidManifest.xml, in application label.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="asset_statements"
        android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />
```

this will solve your 1 and 2.

2) Fill in your autoVerify property correctly.This will solve your 3.

3) Upload assetlinks.json file at myinstnatapp.droppages.com/.well-known

By the way, If your site can be accessed by HTTP mode, You have to switch to accessible HTTPS mode. If you don't have a URL that can be accessed by HTTPS, GitHub it's good choice!

If your site is a static web site, You should include the .well-known folder and its contents in the _config.yml file, like this:

```
include: [".well-known"]
```

Then you can access the .well-known/assetlinks.json file in HTTPS mode.

Here is an example of my configuration:

```
https://github.com/doncc/doncc.github.io
```

Hope you will succeed!

Answer (score 0):

For your Instant App to work, both your installed-app and instant-app must support App Links.

> https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/prepare.html#app-links
>
> Both your instant and installable versions of your app must implement
>   the Android App Links feature introduced in Android 6.0. App Links
>   provide the primary mechanism for connecting URLs to discrete
>   activities within your app.
>
> Android Instant Apps uses URLs for all navigation. When a user taps a
>   link to your instant app, they go to a specific activity within your
>   app. If the link fails or the user taps the link on an unsupported
>   device, the browser opens and shows your website.

This involves configuring your manifest(s) to associate with certain URLs and uploading a kind of certificate (assetlinks.json) to your website at a specific location. See this doc for an introduction: [Handling Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/)

Now, the “Declare Website Association” step you are on creates the certificate, the assetlinks.json file, as well as checks to see if you have already set up App Links (your website and the manifest). This certificate allows Google to basically verify that your [app] with this [package name] and [fingerprint] is automatically allowed to handle the [URLs] of your website. This doc goes into more setup detail: [Add Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html)